# list data type haskell with bounds

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I have the following type definitions to represent cards:

```
data Suit = Hearts | Spades | Diamonds | Clubs
data Rank = Numeric Integer | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
data Card = Card Rank Suit
data Deck = None | Cons Card Deck
```

Numeric Integer represents ranks from 2 to 10.

Now I want to write a function to get the full deck:

```
fullDeck :: Deck
```

How could I generate the full deck in the most elegant way? I understand that some of these definitions are ugly but I have no freedom to choose this.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does something like

```
-- Not sure why you're reinventing a list but
fromList :: [Card] -> Deck
fromList = foldr Cons None

fullDeck = fromList [Card r s | s <- [Hearts, Spades, Diamonds, Clubs]
                              , r <- map Numeric [2..9]++[Jack, Queen, King, Ace]]
```

Look nice? we're just using list comprehensions to generate a list of all possibilities than smashing it into a `Deck`.

Answer (score 6):

You could consider using the [universe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe) package. It doesn't really make the code much easier, but it's fun. =)

Here's how it would look.

```
import Data.Universe

data Suit = Hearts | Spades | Diamonds | Clubs deriving (Bounded, Enum)
data Rank = Numeric Integer | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

instance Universe Suit
instance Universe Rank where
    universe = map Numeric [2..10] ++ [Jack, Queen, King, Ace]

instance Finite Suit
instance Finite Rank
```

Now you can use `universeF :: [(Rank, Suit)]` as your full deck of cards. If you really want custom `Card` and `Deck` types, you can add just a few lines of code:

```
data Card = Card Rank Suit
instance Universe Card where
    universe = [Card rank suit | (rank, suit) <- universeF]
instance Finite Card

data Deck = None | Cons Card Deck
fullDeck = foldr Cons None universeF
```

Comment: +1 for "it doesn't really make anything easier, but it's fun". There should be more fun in programming!

Comment: +1 :)
I will check this for personal education then.

Answer (score 4):

Quickly hacking around, came up with this:

```
data Suit = Hearts | Spades | Diamonds | Clubs deriving Show
data Rank = Numeric Integer | Jack | Queen | King | Ace deriving Show
data Card = Card Rank Suit deriving Show
data Deck = None | Cons Card Deck deriving Show

cards :: [Card]
cards = do
  suit <- [Hearts, Spades, Diamonds, Clubs]
  rank <- Ace : (map Numeric [2..10]) ++ [Jack, Queen, King]
  return (Card rank suit)

listToDeck :: [Card] -> Deck
listToDeck [] = None
listToDeck (x:xs) = Cons x $ listToDeck xs
```

Is that elegant enough? :D

Comment: Well, I consider Ace to be the highest card but it's not a problem, I will fix that. However, using foldr (as jozefg suggested) is a bit more elegant :) Although both your solutions are mostly the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@jozefg's answer is probably the easiest way, but an alternative that could make other operations easier is to defined `Enum` and `Bounded` instances for `Suit` and `Rank`:

```
data Suit = Hearts | Spades | Diamonds | Clubs deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Bounded)
data Rank = Numeric Integer | Jack | Queen | King | Ace deriving (Eq, Show)
data Card = Card Rank Suit deriving (Eq, Show)
data Deck = None | Cons Card Deck deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Bounded Rank where
    minBound = Numeric 2
    maxBound = Ace

instance Enum Rank where
    toEnum n
        | n <= 1 = error "Invalid card value"
        | n <= 10 = Numeric $ toInteger n
        | n == 11 = Jack
        | n == 12 = Queen
        | n == 13 = King
        | n == 14 = Ace
        | otherwise = error "Invalid card value"
    fromEnum (Numeric i) = fromEnum i
    fromEnum Jack = 11
    fromEnum Queen = 12
    fromEnum King = 13
    fromEnum Ace = 14

range :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => [a]
range = [minBound .. maxBound]

fromList :: [Card] -> Deck
fromList = foldr Cons None

fullDeck :: Deck
fullDeck = fromList [Card r s | r <- range, s <- range]
```

It's rather easy to let the compiler just derive the instances for `Suit`, but it's a little more involved (but straightforward) for `Rank`.  Strictly speaking, you don't need `range`, but I think it's kinda cool.  Another advantage is that you can do things like `[Numeric 2, Numeric 5, .. Ace]` and get back `[Numeric 2, Numeric 5, Numeric 8, Jack, Ace]`.

#### EDIT

If you can't change the definition of the data types to add the deriving statements, you can do it like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
data Suit = Hearts | Spades | Diamonds | Clubs

-- etc

deriving instance Eq Suit
deriving instance Show Suit
deriving instance Enum Suit
deriving instance Bounded Suit
```

Comment: Yeah, I think your suggestions will be helpful for me soon. Thanks for that.

One more issue is that I cannot change the module where the data types are defined (but I could change the module where I work with these data types). So instantiation of Enum Rank is not a problem since I do the manual instantiation. But could I ask compiler to automatically derive Enum instantiation in my module (and not near the data type definition)?

Comment: @jjauhien I think you're looking for standalone deriving declarations.  If you put `{-# Language StandaloneDeriving #-} as the first line of your module, then you can do `deriving instance Eq Suit`, `deriving instance Show Suit`, etc on a line by themselves.  The ones you really need are just `Enum` and `Bounded`, which are easy enough to define by hand if for whatever reason you can't use that language extension.